# Effects of Erasing and Already Erased Command

Tags: memory, uart, erase, solid-state-drive, flash-memory

I feel as if this question should be trivial but I have looked online and can't seem to come across an answer. I was hoping that someone would be able to answer this as insightful as possible...

Right now I am writing code to erase a device. Once I send the command through the UART the response I get is 'write done." which is what I want but then immediately after I get the same response again meaning that the code is running twice (which is a bug I intend to fix) therefore erasing an already erased device.

Then I got to thinking, memories only have a fixed set of P/E cycles because the current degrades the oxides but if the device is already erased and another erase is sent does that damage the device as much as programming and erasing once will?

Any info on this matter would be great! Thank you.